# Best way to assert for numpy.array equality?

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy

I want to make some unit-tests for my app, and I need to compare two arrays. Since `array.__eq__` returns a new array (so `TestCase.assertEqual` fails), what is the best way to assert for equality?

Currently I'm using

```
self.assertTrue((arr1 == arr2).all())
```

but I don't really like it

Comment: note that your example can yield True unexpectedly, e.g. `(np.array([1, 1]) == np.array([1])).all()` will yield True

Comment: self.assertTrue(np.array_equal(array1, array2))

Answer (score 169):

check out the assert functions in [`numpy.testing`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.testing.html), e.g.

`assert_array_equal`

for floating point arrays equality test might fail and `assert_almost_equal` is more reliable.

**update**

A few versions ago numpy obtained `assert_allclose` which is now my favorite since it allows us to specify both absolute and relative error and doesn't require decimal rounding as the closeness criterion.

Comment: How does this interact with unittest? I think that some words on the matter would be useful.

Comment: I never use unittest. However, it works very well with nosetests which are used by numpy, scipy and statsmodels. Just use the asserts inside a test function or method.

Comment: This doesn't verify that the two arguments are both numpy arrays. For example, it would succeed on an array and a list. For testing, it might be useful to verify that these are actually arrays, but I guess it would require manually checking the type?

Comment: No, it doesn't. We use it only to verify numbers, some functions return scalars or tuples or numpy arrays or pandas Series. When we want to verify also the class or the `dtype`, then we do so separately. Pandas also has assert function that also check that the index and column names are as expected, which, AFAIK, use the numpy assert to verify the numerical values and maybe assert_equal for other dtypes.

Comment: @RamonMartinez assert_allclose seems to play nicely with unittest :)

Comment: @RamonMartinez if you use Python's `unittest` you can use `self.assertIsNone(np.testing.assert_array_equal(a, b))` as it returns `None` if the arrays are equal.

Answer (score 35):

I think `(arr1 == arr2).all()` looks pretty nice. But you could use:

```
numpy.allclose(arr1, arr2)
```

but it's not quite the same.

An alternative, almost the same as your example is:

```
numpy.alltrue(arr1 == arr2)
```

Note that scipy.array is actually a reference numpy.array. That makes it easier to find the documentation.

Answer (score 25):

I find that using
`self.assertEqual(arr1.tolist(), arr2.tolist())`
is the easiest way of comparing arrays with unittest.

I agree it's not the prettiest solution and it's probably not the fastest but it's probably more uniform with the rest of your test cases, you get all the unittest error description and it's really simple to implement.

Comment: Note this won't work well with `np.nan`, since `np.nan != np.nan` and the `self.assertEqual` attempt won't be able to account for that.

Answer (score 8):

Since Python 3.2 you can use `assertSequenceEqual(array1.tolist(), array2.tolist())`.

This has the added value of showing you the exact items in which the arrays differ.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work well when arrays are of `float` type. We really need `assertSequenceAlmostEqual`

Answer (score 8):

```
self.assertTrue(np.array_equal(x, y, equal_nan=True))
```

`equal_nan = True` if you want to `np.nan == np.nan` returns `True`

or you can use [numpy.allclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) to compare with torelance.

Answer (score 7):

In my tests I use this:

```
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal(arr1, arr2)
```

Comment: This is best, because it gives an error message pointing to where the error is

Answer (score 3):

Use numpy

```
numpy.array_equal(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.linalg.norm(arr1 - arr2) < 1e-6`

Comment: Please add some context

Answer (score 0):

Using built-in [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/unittest.html) module works okay for nested array (deep equality) using Python 3.10.12

```
self.assertEqual([
    ["1","0","1","1","0","1","1"]
], [
    ["1","0","1","1","0","1","x"]
])
```

and it prints a nice output message for failure.

```
First differing element 0:
['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1']
['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'x']

- [['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1']]
?                                  ^

+ [['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', 'x']]
?
```

**A note based on your question**: if you're always comparing a pointer to the same array (or modifying the array in place then comparing it to itself) the result will yield true every time... so that will be a mistake.