# Doing a groupby and rolling window on a Pandas Dataframe with a multilevel index leads to a duplicated index entry

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

If I do a groupby() followed by a rolling() calculation with a multi-level index, one of the levels in the index is repeated - most odd. I am using Pandas 0.18.1

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 1, 10, 20], [1, 2, 30, 40], [1, 3, 50, 60],
                        [2, 1, 11, 21], [2, 2, 31, 41], [2, 3, 51, 61]],
                  columns=['id', 'date', 'd1', 'd2'])

df.set_index(['id', 'date'], inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(level='id').rolling(window=2)['d1'].sum()
print(df)
print(df.index)
```

The output is as follows

```
id  id  date
1   1   1        NaN
        2       40.0
        3       80.0
2   2   1        NaN
        2       42.0
        3       82.0
Name: d1, dtype: float64
MultiIndex(levels=[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
           names=[u'id', u'id', u'date'])
```

What is odd is that the id column now shows up twice in the multi-index. Moving the ['d1'] column selection around doesn't make any difference.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14013).

But version with `apply` works nice, this alternative is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#groupby-syntax-with-window-and-resample-operations) (only `d1` was moved to `apply`):

```
df = df.groupby(level='id').d1.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=2).sum())
print(df)
id  date
1   1        NaN
    2       40.0
    3       80.0
2   1        NaN
    2       42.0
    3       82.0
Name: d1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. Will switch to apply(rolling) until this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas==1.1.1`, it looks like this can also be done without `.apply`

Using `.apply`

```
method1 = test_df.groupby(level="id").d1.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=2).sum())
print(method1)
id  date
1   1        NaN
    2       40.0
    3       80.0
2   1        NaN
    2       42.0
    3       82.0
Name: d1, dtype: float64
```

Without using `.apply`

```
method2 = test_df.groupby(level="id").d1.rolling(window=2).sum()
print(method2)
id  date
1   1        NaN
    2       40.0
    3       80.0
2   1        NaN
    2       42.0
    3       82.0
Name: d1, dtype: float64
```

[Check equality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49150704/4057186)

```
try:
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(method1.to_numpy(), method2.to_numpy())
    print("Matching outputs")
except AssertionError as err:
    print("MisMatching outputs")
```

Result of checking equality

```
Matching outputs
```