# ValueError for numpy array with unittest Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unit-testing

I have the the following question.

I have these function:

```
def string_to_2Darray(flat_string):

    """converts a string of type '0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0'"""

    array1d = np.fromstring(flat_string, dtype=int, sep=',')
    return np.reshape(array1d, (-1,3))
```

and I wrote a unittest Class for this function which goes like that:

```
class StringTo2DArray(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_string_2DArray(self):
        string_example_0 = '0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0'
        array_example_0 = string_to_2Darray(string_example_0)
        print(array_example_0)
        print(type(array_example_0))
        self.assertEqual([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]], array_example_0)
```

See that I am adding some print statements within the body of the test_string_2Darray module within the StringTo2DArray class in the unittest.

When I run python -m unittest then I get the following Error message:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I don't know why it happens since the string is correctly transformed to 2D numpy array and does not match the array `[[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]` that I passed in the assert. Equal for my test.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302949/best-way-to-assert-for-numpy-array-equality/3303083#3303083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Roger Almengor,

As @lllllIIIIll replied, it's a known bug in Python's TestCase implementation.
The assertEqual(a, b) implemenation assumes the a==b operation will return one True or one False, but if it returns a composited value which including multiple boolean values, it'll raise this error. E.g, if the a, b are numpy's data array or Tensorflow's tensor, this bug will be triggered.

There are two solutions to work around this bug:

> 1. Converting the numpy data arry or tensors to a list, because a_list==b_list will return one boolean value, so TestCase assertEqual() could handle it correctly.
> 2. Using numpy or tesorflow's customized version TestCase implementation, they have their own versions' for assertEqual() function implenentation for numpy array and tensors, e.g.
>      assert_array_equal()# In numpy, 
>      or assertAllEqual() ## in
>      Tensorflow.test.TestCase

Comment: I like to use tensorflow.test.TestCase' assertAllEqual(), assertAllClose(), assertAllXXXXX() functions to handle both numpy's data array and tensor's value comparison work.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/TestCase#assertAllEqual

Answer (score 3):

You can check if two numpy arrays are equal using functions from the [numpy.testing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.testing.html) suite.

In your case, you could replace

```
self.assertEqual([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]], array_example_0)
```

with

```
numpy.testing.assert_array_equal([[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]], array_example_0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition, 1d arrays can be asserted by assertCountEqual.